# Scrapy Link Extractor Denying Previously Scraped Links

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am building a crawler using the CrawlSpider class in Scarpy. I suspect that the link extractors loop over same links over and over again. Is there a way to restrict link extractor and deny links that have already been scraped? Can this be done without regular expressions in the deny input ?

```
My Rules look like this:
```

{

```
rules = (
    #Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor((allow='profile')), follow=True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(deny='feedback\.html'),callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

}
And my parse_item is:
```

{

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    element = hxs.select('//table[@id="profilehead"]/tr/td/a/@href').extract()
    try:
        open('urls.txt', 'a').write(element[0])
        open('urls.txt', 'a').write('\n')
    except IndexError:
        # Site doesn't have link to another website
        pass
```

}

Comment: If you post your full spider code and the website that you're trying to crawl, we could take a look to see if the same links are being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I think scrapy don't follow already visited links. however if you want to restrict some part not being followed then you can try something like this

`restrict_xpaths=('//a[starts-with(@title,"Next ")]')),`

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html